# How to get Emacs´s eval-last-sexp in DrRacket?

Tags: emacs, scheme, racket

I am wondering how to evaluate a single s-expression in DrRacket. I am looking for a key which does the same as C-x C-e in Emacs, which evaluates the s-expression just in front of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that with vanilla DrRacket, which was an intentional design decision. You can read [this blog post](https://blog.racket-lang.org/2009/03/the-drscheme-repl-isnt-the-one-in-emacs.html) (it's an old blog post, so it refers to the obsolete DrScheme/PLT Scheme) for the full reason why DrRacket wasn't designed with that kind of evaluation model.

That said, it is probably possible to add a feature like this as a [plugin](http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/).

Answer (score 0):

DrRacket is built on top of Racket. Racket, like most Scheme implementations, provides a 'read-eval-print-loop' that is suitable for interactive development.  Once you locate the Racket executable you can a) execute it directly from your computer's shell or b) integrate it into Emacs.

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v5.3.4.
> (list 1 2 3)
'(1 2 3)
^D
$ which racket
/usr/local/scheme/bin/racket  # my location
```